# Sum based on values in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

Hello I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "1"],
                   "code" : ["T", "N", "N", "T"],
                   "amount" : [100, 200, 300 ,400]})
```

And I need to calculate

1. sumT = sum of "amount" for each "ID" where "code" == "T"
2. sumN = sum of "amount" for each "ID" where "code" == "N"

So I need result like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df.groupby(['ID','code']).agg(sum).unstack()
new_df.columns = ['Sum T','Sum N']
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Is there other way without creation multiindex ?

Comment: its the optimized way, to do it. You can again reset the index. I updated my answer to match the expected output.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I gave you best ansewer